# Can I reduce the time of containercreating period in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

When we run `kubectl apply -f`, we create a new pod in Kubernetes. But it takes about 5 seconds to arrive `Running` status even though the image has been already pulled in the node. Before that, the pod is in `containercreating` status. I Run `kubectl describe`  to see the events and found that the scheduling is very fast but the gap between scheduled and imagepulling is about 3 seconds , and the container starting time is about 2 seconds. I wonder if I can reduce the time of containercreating time.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The target latency between Creation to Running is ~5 sec (if the image is pre-pulled). Your Pods' creation times are meeting both the scheduling time goal and the API latency goal. There was a [discussion](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/3954) regarding that topic which resulted in the current SLA. And further [Enhancement Proposals](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/issues/1446) (example) are rejected.

However you may want to review the [Scheduler Performance Tuning](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/scheduler-perf-tuning/) but bear in mind that it would be relevant for large Kubernetes clusters mainly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have further questions. Why it is designed like this? And where does it wait for several seconds  before startup?

Comment: I am afraid this is a question for the actual developers.